# What does "And she promises the earth to me..." mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, lyrics, poetry

I like the famous song. But I can't understand what does "to promise the earth" mean. Does she want to give the Earth to him? I suspect native English speakers find it a strange question. Maybe I don't know all meanings of 'promise'. Could anyone explain to me this line?

Comment: What famous song? "Girl" by The Beatles?

Comment: Yes, it is. "...and I believe her"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard idiom in English. *The earth* here is a metaphor that symbolizes the impossible, the immoderate, or the unfulfillable:

> **promise (someone) the earth** (or **moon**)<sup>[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1281085#m_en_us1281085.014)</sup>
>   make extravagant promises to someone that are unlikely to be fulfilled:
>    *interactive technology titillates, promises the earth, but delivers nothing*

The origin of this idiom is probably from the third temptation of Jesus (in the Bible), where the devil tempts him with the ridiculous promise of *all the kingdoms of the world*:

> Again, the devil taketh him up into an exceeding high mountain, and sheweth him all the kingdoms of the world, and the glory of them; And saith unto him, All these things will I give thee, if thou wilt fall down and worship me.
>   <sub>— [Matthew 4:8–9 (The Bible, King James Version)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%204:8-9&version=KJV)</sub>

Comment: @Andrey: You're welcome! She couldn't give him the earth even if she wanted to—she doesn't own it! :)

Comment: It's another way of saying "promise [someone] everything".